# How do I use list comprehension for slicing in a 2d matrix with multiple entries?

Tags: python, data-science

I am trying to have i in range 0 to 20. I have tried a for loop, but then I deleted it due to run time. How would one do it for List comprehension?

```
    finallinearsystem = [
        [np.transpose(i), np.transpose(pts_3d[i]) , np.dot(-y[i],np.transpose(pts_3d[i]))],
        [np.transpose(pts_3d[i]), np.transpose(i) , np.dot(-x[i],np.transpose(pts_3d[i]))],]
```

Comment: I don't think list comprehension vs for loop is a performance question -- if the computation is expensive the looping mechanism isn't going to have a substantial impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you accepted my answer already, but I think your performance issue isn't because of the for loop, but because you're doing several expensive computations multiple times.

I'd try this:

```
final_linear_system = []
    for i in range(20)
        transposed_i = np.transpose(i) # you're doing this twice
        transposed_pts_3d_i = np.transpose(pts_3d[i]) # you were doing this 4 times
        
        final_linear_system.append([transposed_i, transposed_pts_3d_i, np.dot(-y[i],transposed_pts_3d_i)])
        final_linear_system.append([transposed_i, transposed_pts_3d_i, np.dot(-x[i],transposed_pts_3d_i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add two elements to the array for each value of i, this can be done with a nested comprehension

```
print([j for i in range(5) for j in ([f"{i}a",f"{i}a"],[f"{i}b",f"{i}b"])])
# [['0a', '0a'], ['0b', '0b'], ['1a', '1a'], ['1b', '1b'], ['2a', '2a'], ['2b', '2b'], ['3a', '3a'], ['3b', '3b'], ['4a', '4a'], ['4b', '4b']]
```

or:

```
finallinearsystem = [
    j for i in range(20)
    for j in (
        [np.transpose(i), np.transpose(pts_3d[i]) , np.dot(-y[i],np.transpose(pts_3d[i]))],
        [np.transpose(pts_3d[i]), np.transpose(i) , np.dot(-x[i],np.transpose(pts_3d[i]))]
    )
]
```